Authenticating an application server with a backend server
I have an application server that is running an SPA and its associated NodeJs backend (API). On this server there are a couple other services that are accessed by the API and require authentication.
Up to this step all is clear, the local services use the same authorization mechanism as the API - JWT. Basically the client logs in, receives a token, then uses that token to make requests to the API which forwards the token to the requests it makes on the behalf of the client to the local services.
However - this is where I'm having trouble - these services need to communicate with other services from a backend server. The client's JWT is no longer valid in this case, because the client may have logged in using SSO or other external identity providers to which the backend server does not have access.
I need a way to authenticate the requests made by the services on the application server to the backend server.
How can I achieve this? What are the go-to solutions for such situations?
The application server cannot be fully trusted since it may be deployed on-premise on the client's network.

Based on the previous answer and some private discussions, I thought about the next solution:
For each client generate a private-public key pair and store the public key on the backend server. The private key will be sent in an encrypted archive via email to the client, so that the client will copy paste the private key into the application UI, which then stores it onto the application server.
The application server uses this private key to generate an access token which will be used to sign all requests made to the backend.
The backend uses the paired key to decrypt and validate the token and thus validate the authenticity of the requests.
If I want to remove access for one client, all I have to do is delete its associated key from the backend server.

To solve this you should design access tokens issued to clients and received by your backend APIs to be issued by you as the data owner and avoid ever receiving foreign tokens that you cannot trust or whose claims you cannot control.
In OAuth the usual thing is that a client always gets tokens issued by the authorization server (AS) of the organization that develops the client and APIs. This enables the client to call the organization's APIs.
Logins for the client use the AS which can route to identity providers (IDP) from business partners when required. Eg the AS login process might first prompt for a username or email, then look up user data, then apply logic to route to a particular IDP. The AS receives and validates IDP tokens then issues its own tokens to the client.
This enables you to control access tokens issued to clients and received by your APIs, so that you maintain trust regardless of deployment domains.
If it is difficult to migrate to such a solution then you might implement some interim solutions that issue conistent tokens to the client after validating IDP tokens.

sounds like a good lead, thanks!
